# MySQL - Query to order by second column if first column value is same

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user_job_application` 
ORDER BY `user_job_application`.`user_id` DESC
```

It gives the table result like image preview.
but when `user_id`is same then, I want to fetch result `order by user_job_application_date desc`

[image]

Comment: You can sort on multiple columns, and you can sort different columns in different directions - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Answer (score 8):

We can `ORDER` results using multiple columns.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user_job_application` 
ORDER BY `user_job_application`.`user_id` DESC, user_job_application_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `user_job_application`
ORDER BY `user_job_application`.`user_id` DESC,
         `user_job_application`.`user_job_application_date` DESC;
```

Just put a comma after your DESC and add the next ORDER BY item.